# SQL find and group consecutive number in rows without duplicate

Tags: sql

So I have a table like this:

```
Taxi  Client  Time
Tom   A       1
Tom   A       2
Tom   B       3
Tom   A       4 
Tom   A       5
Tom   A       6
Tom   B       7
Tom   B       8     
Bob   A       1
Bob   A       2
Bob   A       3
```

and the expected result will be like this:

```
Tom    3
Bob    1
```

I have used the partition function to count the consecutive value but the result become this:

```
Tom    A     2
Tom    A     3
Tom    B     2
Bob    A     2
```

Please help, I am not good in English, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand where the "3" comes from.  Can you provide more explanation?

Comment: Guys, 3 come from the number of consecutive client, so the first AA count as 1, then AAA count 1, and BB count one as well, so total of 3. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation of a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can solve it using window functions:

```
select taxi, count(*)
from (select t.taxi, t.client, count(*) as num_times
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by taxi order by time) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by taxi, client order by time) as seqnum_c
            from t
           ) t
      group by t.taxi, t.client, (seqnum - seqnum_c)
      having count(*) >= 2
    )
group by taxi;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your effort. However, I want the count of consecutive time, not the highest count of consecutive rows, so even there are 3 or more consecutive rows, it only count as 1 time, thanks

Comment: @Anthony5 . . . I think that is what I originally had then I double checked against your answer, saw the final table with four rows, and thought that was what you wanted.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thanks. You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

use distinct count

```
  select taxi ,count( distinct cient)
  from table_name
  group by taxi
```

It seems your expected output is wrong

Comment: That does not get the desired results - Tom has 2 distinct clients, not 3

Comment: @FizzBuzz you are right it seems op mistakes in times of expected output

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you get the number 3 from. If you're trying to do what your question says and group by client in consecutive order only and then get the number of different groups, I can help you out with the following query. Bob has 1 group and Tom has 4.

Partition by taxi, ORDER BY taxi, time and check if this client matches the previous client for this taxi. If yes, do not count this row. If no, count this row, this is a new group.

```
SELECT FEE.taxi,
       SUM(FEE.clientNotSameAsPreviousInSequence)
FROM
(
    SELECT taxi,
           CASE
               WHEN PreviousClient IS NULL THEN
                   1
               WHEN PreviousClient <> client THEN
                   1
               ELSE
                   0
           END AS clientNotSameAsPreviousInSequence
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
               LAG(client) OVER (PARTITION BY taxi ORDER BY taxi, time) AS PreviousClient
        FROM table
    ) taxisWithPreviousClient
) FEE
GROUP BY FEE.taxi;
```

Comment: Guys, 3 come from the number of consecutive client, so the first AA count as 1, then AAA count 1, and BB count one as well, so total of 3. Sorry for my bad english