# count consecutive record with timestamp interval requirement

Tags: sql

ref to this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693161/sql-find-and-group-consecutive-number-in-rows-without-duplicate), I used the answer provided by @Gordon Linoff:

```
    select taxi, count(*)
from (select t.taxi, t.client, count(*) as num_times
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by taxi order by time) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by taxi, client order by time) as seqnum_c
            from t
           ) t
      group by t.taxi, t.client, (seqnum - seqnum_c)
      having count(*) >= 2
    )
group by taxi;
```

and got my answer perfectly like this:

```
Tom    3  (AA count as 1, AAA count as 1 and BB count as 1, so total of 3 count)
Bob    1
```

But now I would like to add one more condition which is the time between two consecutive clients for same taxi should not be longer than 2hrs.

I know that I should probably use row_number() again and calculate the time difference with datediff. But I have no idea where to add and how to do.

So any suggestion?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a bit more logic.  In this case, I would use `lag()` to calculate  the groups:

```
select taxi, count(*)
from (select t.taxi, t.client, count(*) as num_times
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when prev_client = client and 
                                 prev_time > time - interval '2 hour'
                            then 1
                            else 0
                       end) over (partition by client order by time) as grp
            from (select t.*,
                         lag(client) over (partition by taxi order by time) as prev_client,
                         lag(time) over (partition by taxi order by time) as prev_time
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
      group by t.taxi, t.client, grp
      having count(*) >= 2
    )
group by taxi;
```

Note:  You don't specify the database, so this uses ISO/ANSI standard syntax for date/time comparisons.  You can adjust this for your actual database.